# Laptop Boots to a default screen

Tags: windows

I boot into my work laptop, I see that all my files are not there and all the settings are in default.
It tells me that there is a problem signing in to my account. What should I do?

Edit: I figured out that I booted as an administrator. How can boot into my own account?

Edit 2:
I logged in and logged out a few times and that did not work.
I also tried signing in using my company domain but it still did not work.
I restarted my laptop and logged in and logged out and it worked.
Why did that work and not when I logged and logged out in the starting?

Comment: Can you precise if the target account is a local account or a domain account.

Comment: It is a domain.

Comment: If you log off that account, can you now login as your account?

Comment: I edited my question, was busy :)